# Resolve a promise only after user provided an input in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-promise

Assume that I have installed a 3rd party react component library named `something` which calls the `async` function given to it via `onRequestName` `prop`.

`something` will use the resolved data from the async function to render the result.

```js
<Something onRequestName={this.asyncFunction}/>
```

My `async` function **requires** user input, and I want to resolve it **only** when user provides an input (otherwise I should reject the promise).

```js
asyncFunction = async () => {
  // get user input and then resolve this funciton
}
```

**How should I proceed in this situation?**

the only source I found that discusses a similar situation is [this](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/async-dialogs.html) which is not concerned about react at all.

I'm not aware of any other stackoverflow question that addresses this issue. If you know about it let me know.

---

Currently I'm doing something like this(which looks crazy wrong):

```js
// my async function sets a resolve in State of the component
asyncFunction = () => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    this.setState({resolve: res, reject: rej, showForm: true})
  };
}
```

And then I call `resolve` which is available in state when user provides the input:

```js
// resolve promise on user input

    {showForm &&
      <form 
         onSubmit={() => {
          this.state.resolve(this.state.userInput) // <-- resolve is called here
          this.setState({showForm: false})
         }}
      >
        <label>
          Name:
          <input 
            type="text" 
            value={this.state.value} 
            onChange={e => this.setState({userInput: e.target.value})} 
          />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't look that unreasonable IMO, though if `otherwise I should reject the promise` maybe do you want to call `reject` after a `setTimeout`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I wonder If I'm wrong because I have not seen this pattern anywhere else.

Comment: It's a kind of odd thing to have to do, so it wouldn't be all that surprising to not see this particular situation being described elsewhere, but what you're doing *works* and doesn't take much code, so I personally wouldn't worry about it much, though there might be a nicer pattern

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Don't you mean you want to **execute** your async function instead of **resolving** the Promise ? You can't decide when your Promise will be resolved, it's I/O.

Comment: @PierreCapo I want to know how I could delay resolving the promise until user provides the input.

Comment: Check if the use provided some input. then you call resolve.